# Removing leading spaces on Pascals Triangle

Tags: java

I have some example code below to print Pascals Triangle. (I am using the test case = 14 on scanner) The code works, but there are leading spaces in the result. How do I remove these spaces in front of the triangle?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PascalsTriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++) {
            int pascal = 1;
            System.out.format("%"+(rows-i)*2+"s","");)

            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
                 System.out.format("%4d", pascal);
                 pascal = pascal* (i - j) / (j + 1);
            }
            System.out.println();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: pascal isnt defined in your program.. are you sure.. it works?

Comment: Sorry, int pascal = 1 instead of int triangle = 1.

Comment: change in code also please

Comment: It's very bad practice to get some code from somewhere and expect someone to fix it for you. Got the code? Read it and understand what it is doing. Then you'll (a) learn an important skill in programming that you'll be able to use in real life, and (b) know exactly what causes the leading blanks and be able to fix it easily yourself.

Comment: The leading space comes from the first `System.out.format` (Smart way to do it !)

Comment: I am not expecting it to be fixed, it works as planned. I am looking for help with the system.out.printf or system.out.format line. I do not understand where the spaces come from.

Comment: Can you explain where in the line @AxelH? It's quite confusing to look at!

Comment: But @RealSkeptic is right, if try to understand these few line. There is only two loops. Since the space is on each line, you should find easily where it should come, some you only need to check some block of code.

Comment: @twostart, are you familiar with `String.format()` ? It is create a %###s depending on the number of trailing space needed. Do some research if needed.

Comment: @AxelH I am somewhat familiar, I believe the spaces come from the (rows-i)*2 part in the System.out.format line, but still cannot get the program to display without leading spaces while still in a "triangle" shape.

Comment: If it's about System.out.format, then ask about that and test exactly that. Write a program that has only one line with that command and put in stuff. Pascal's Triangle is totally irrelevant in this context, only unnecessary code to rummage through. You want to understand the core commands before you put them into something larger.

Comment: The first System.out.format receive String like %1s, %2s, %4s, .... (not in that order) with the line see (`(rows-i)*2` = number of space on that row)... comment that line and the space disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is you are outputting your numbers in 4 char 'blocks' this line looks after that part;

```
String output = String.format("%4d", number);
```

The following would output the number to the left of the 'box' - Although the whitespace would now be trailing.

```
String output = String.format("%-4d", number);
```

It all depends on what the maximum value of n you are going to use. For example, you can decide that each number will take 4 characters (if all the numbers are 9999 or less--actually, with Pascal's triangle with 20 rows, you'll need at least 5 characters). Then you'll need to adjust the number of spaces you print out in each row of the triangle.